# add kapt androidx room in gradle makes data binding error

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding, android-room, android-databinding

After I add `kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha05"`

I get error when doing data binding. Here is my app gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "insure.onoff"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    // Gradle automatically adds 'android.test.runner' as a dependency.
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'

    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
    applicationVariants.all {
        variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "./" + outputFileName
            }
    }
}

dependencies {
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha05"
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.1-rc01'
    implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0'

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0'

    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

    // AWS Dependencies
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.11.1"
    implementation "com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-core:2.11.1"
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-userpools:2.11.1") { transitive = true }
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-auth-ui:2.11.1") { transitive = true }

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.36.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"

    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"

}
```

project gradle :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Error :** 
[image]

My Android Studio version :

```
Android Studio 3.3
Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5199772, built on December 25, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.12.5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get databinding errors, they are usually the result of a compilation error within the code.

Using the picture you have posted as reference, there are 4 Icons on the vertical toolbar on the left side of the screen. The top icon is the green hammer. Click the icon just below that (the 2nd one, it looks like two screens layered on top of each other). Clicking this icon opens up a different view that describes in detail what the compiler did not like - you generally will find what is  causing the problems.

You can also run "gradle build -debug" or some  other debug tracing cmd for gradle that will print in detail what the errors are.

Double check kotlin is compiling to your target jvm version 1.8

If all else fails, try clean/build + invalidate/cache + restart. Hope this helps.